# Programmatically transfer images through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

How to send a image file from one device to another using bluetooth in Android programmatically. I Can send text files correctly,but when trying to send image files it shows error.

Sample code is here:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, url);

  values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, deviceAddress);

  values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);

  Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

  values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);

  getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Here `url` refers to the path of the image.

Comment: `it shows error` - I think we'd like to see the error.

Comment: The error is Cant open file for outbound info 27. On device it shows BLUETOOTH SHARE: file unknown file not send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code for this problem :

```
 File file=new File(imagePath);
 Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);

 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, uri.toString());

  values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, deviceAddress);

  values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);

  Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

  values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);

  getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: "BluetoothShare" is not accessible now....code is hidden...how can we use it????? please reply.

Comment: unfortunately this answer does not help very much, because `BluetoothShare` is unknown... can you elaborate?

Comment: found it meanwhile, see this [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6531504/1545993)