# I want to send images and files using code for sending messages over my bluetooth app

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, file-sharing

---

I have been developing a bluetooth chat app while taking reference from developers code of bluetooth chat. My app is connecting to devices and sending and receiving messages but I am not able to understand how should I send Images over chat. I want to browse gallery and then send it through chat. I also want to send files using totally different activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically transfer images through bluetooth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191064/programmatically-transfer-images-through-bluetooth)

Comment: @Alexandr I have implemented chat using sockets in my app. I want to send images and files using this sockets only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode and decode your bitmap with Base64 and send it as String via Socket. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768973/2308720) for more details.

You can also split String to multiple messages and join them during receiving.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want it less resource hungry you can implement the BIP profile