# Using Bluetooth Share to transfer file in android

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, transfer

I want to transfer files using Bluetooth in Android.

I came across this :
    [How to send file using bluetooth on android programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921384/how-to-send-file-using-bluetooth-on-android-programatically)

Answer to this question in the above link.

But i am not getting any exception and also, none of the files are getting transferred.
Please let me know if i have to add any provider or anything in manifest other than the Bluetooth permission.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: I faced same problem and at the end I found solution here 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15197776/1037442