# Bluetooth not sending file to other device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

It is already asked but i didn't find any solution. For bluetooth application i am using the `bluetoothShare.class` .

My source code for sending the file to the target device

MainActvity.class:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter
                            .getBondedDevices();
                    final String btDeviceName = selected_deviceName;
                    BluetoothDevice device = null;

                    for (BluetoothDevice itDevice : devices) {
                        if (btDeviceName.equals(itDevice.getName())) {
                            device = itDevice;
                        }
                    }

                    if (device != null) {

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, uri.toString());
                        values.put(BluetoothShare.MIMETYPE, "image/jpeg");
                        values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION,
                                device.getAddress());
                        values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION,
                                BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
                        Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
                        final Uri contentUri = getApplicationContext()
                                .getContentResolver().insert(
                                        BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
                        Log.v(TAG, "Insert contentUri: " + contentUri
                                + "  to device: " + device.getName());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        textStatus
                                .setText("Bluetooth remote device not found");
                    }
                } else {
                    textStatus.setText("Bluetooth not activated");
                }
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No devices found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

and the blueToothShare.class:

```
package process.bluetooth.sendfile.opp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;


public final class BluetoothShare implements BaseColumns {
private BluetoothShare() {
}

public static final String PERMISSION_ACCESS = "android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE";

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri
        .parse("content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp");

public static final String TRANSFER_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.btopp.intent.action.TRANSFER_COMPLETE";

public static final String INCOMING_FILE_CONFIRMATION_REQUEST_ACTION = "android.btopp.intent.action.INCOMING_FILE_NOTIFICATION";

public static final String USER_CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT_ACTION = "android.btopp.intent.action.USER_CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT";

public static final String URI = "uri";

public static final String FILENAME_HINT = "hint";

public static final String _DATA = "_data";

public static final String MIMETYPE = "mimetype";

public static final String DIRECTION = "direction";

public static final String DESTINATION = "destination";

public static final String VISIBILITY = "visibility";

public static final String USER_CONFIRMATION = "confirm";

public static final String STATUS = "status";

public static final String TOTAL_BYTES = "total_bytes";

public static final String CURRENT_BYTES = "current_bytes";

public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

public static final int DIRECTION_OUTBOUND = 0;

public static final int DIRECTION_INBOUND = 1;

public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_PENDING = 0;

public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_CONFIRMED = 1;

public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_AUTO_CONFIRMED = 2;

public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_DENIED = 3;

public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT = 4;

public static final int VISIBILITY_VISIBLE = 0;

public static final int VISIBILITY_HIDDEN = 1;

public static boolean isStatusInformational(int status) {
    return (status >= 100 && status < 200);
}

public static boolean isStatusSuspended(int status) {
    return (status == STATUS_PENDING);
}

public static boolean isStatusSuccess(int status) {
    return (status >= 200 && status < 300);
}

public static boolean isStatusError(int status) {
    return (status >= 400 && status < 600);
}

public static boolean isStatusClientError(int status) {
    return (status >= 400 && status < 500);
}

public static boolean isStatusServerError(int status) {
    return (status >= 500 && status < 600);
}

public static boolean isStatusCompleted(int status) {
    return (status >= 200 && status < 300)
            || (status >= 400 && status < 600);
}

public static final int STATUS_PENDING = 190;

public static final int STATUS_RUNNING = 192;

public static final int STATUS_SUCCESS = 200;

public static final int STATUS_BAD_REQUEST = 400;

public static final int STATUS_FORBIDDEN = 403;

public static final int STATUS_NOT_ACCEPTABLE = 406;

public static final int STATUS_LENGTH_REQUIRED = 411;

public static final int STATUS_PRECONDITION_FAILED = 412;

public static final int STATUS_CANCELED = 490;

public static final int STATUS_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 491;

public static final int STATUS_FILE_ERROR = 492;

public static final int STATUS_ERROR_NO_SDCARD = 493;

public static final int STATUS_ERROR_SDCARD_FULL = 494;

public static final int STATUS_UNHANDLED_OBEX_CODE = 495;

public static final int STATUS_OBEX_DATA_ERROR = 496;

public static final int STATUS_CONNECTION_ERROR = 497;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BluetoothShare class not supported android 4.1 and above. you can use the following intent coding to send file in android version 4.1 and above

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        "com.android.bluetooth",
        "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    file = new File(filepath);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivity(intent);
```

and also some devices in Android v 2.2/2.3 not send the file via bluetoothShare class.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try another solution with BufferedWriter and BufferedReader.

Here is a snipped code:

```
            BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
            Set<BluetoothDevice> mBluetoothAdapter;

            BluetoothAdapter bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
                    .getDefaultAdapter();
            mBluetoothAdapter = bAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            for (BluetoothDevice bc : mBluetoothAdapter) {
                if (bc.getName().indexOf("name_of_bluetoothdevide") != -1) {
                    UUID uuid = UUID
                            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // Standard
                                                                                    // SerialPortService
                                                                                    // ID
                    mmDevice = bc;
                    BluetoothSocket mmSocket = mmDevice
                            .createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                    bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    mmSocket.connect();
                    BufferedWriter Writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    mmSocket.getOutputStream()));
                    Writer.write("Bluetooth connected!");
                    Writer.flush();

                    app.setmSocket(mmSocket);

                    break;
                }
            }
```

And for reading:

```
  BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(mmSocket.getInputStream()));
            receivedMsg = Reader.readLine();
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: forget app.setmSocket(mmSocket); .. this is just for me.

Comment: it shows this error you know how to solve.. ##### ERROR : wrp_wsock_create: wrp_sock_create : out of wsock blocks#####

Comment: Please provide any samples you have or any references i struggle last two weeks for this.

Comment: I have no idea what this error means. what do you want to send?

Comment: i want to send the image. I am able to pair the device but not send data.

Comment: the code I posted is just for sending Strings. If u want to send images you have to send it in bytes and compress it. Look here: http://kamrana.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/sending-images-over-bluetooth-in-android/

Comment: Sorry yar i already go through this one.. i don't want server client model.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you in some way…

```
private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
    Log.d(TAG, "...Sending data: " + message + "...");
    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
        if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
            msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on java code";
        msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";
        errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works with firmware from MediaTek. Tested on Android 4.0.4. Sends the file, without asking anything from the user

```
public boolean SendFileViaBluetoothOPP(String file_path, String destinationMAC){
    BluetoothAdapter btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(btadapter == null)
        return false;

    BluetoothDevice btdev = btadapter.getRemoteDevice(destinationMAC);
    if(btdev == null)
        return false;

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(file_path));

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                        .setType("application/zip");

    List<ResolveInfo> resolvedActivities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent,  0);

    boolean found = false;
    for(ResolveInfo actInfo: resolvedActivities){
        if(actInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.mediatek.bluetooth"))
        {                   
            shareIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(actInfo.activityInfo.packageName, actInfo.activityInfo.name ) );
            shareIntent.putExtra("com.mediatek.bluetooth.sharegateway.extra.DEVICE_ADDRESS", btdev);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found){
        startActivity(shareIntent);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

On older phone from MediaTek with Android 2.2.1 this code launches BluetoothDevicePicker to complete the operation.