# How to get Bluetooth outbound transfer list

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to get the Bluetooth outbound transfer list.

I referred following link and have looked many posts here related to this issue but could not find any solution:
[link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68919/bluetooth-outbound-transfer-list)

Is there a any way that I can use to get the list.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Without actually trying anything: Instead of inserting to the ContentResolver, could you instead query? How to send: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921384/how-to-send-file-using-bluetooth-on-android-programatically

Comment: I have already visited link u posted. Now I m sending files using Bluetooth but I don't have control to know whether it is successfully sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't got time to pick through this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/d65cd7f65d0ba827c94cb9a6c1ef8343b6982d9d/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppTransfer.java  for you, but i think it is capable of what you need.