# Unable to open file for sharing from Bluetooth from external storage

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

I am trying to use intent for sharing a file using bluetooth but i don't know why is it showing me toast "Unable to open file for sharing" i have tried it on different files as well but it do the same, i am sharing my code and permissions i have used in manifest ...

```
    String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Aaa.jpg";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

permissions i have addedso far

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Post your logcat also

Comment: thanks @Exception, i was looking some thing relevant in logcat but i didn't find any thing related to Bluetooth even it doesn't show any thing related to the action i am doing

Answer (score 3):

try This

```
File sourceFile = new File("//mnt/sdcard/TviderFB.apk"); 
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Intent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(sourceFile));
startActivity(intent);
```

Or 
Read this carefully and implement this [How to send file using bluetooth on android programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921384/how-to-send-file-using-bluetooth-on-android-programatically/15197776#15197776)

Or Read This Tutorial to share via bluetooth
http://kpbird.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-send-image-via-bluetooth.html

And Do not  Forget to Declare Permissions in the manifest

Answer (score 2):

If image is in picture folder then path will be like this

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/Aaa.jpg"
```